# Basic JQuery: perform plugin action after loading?

Tags: jquery

I am quite ashamed of asking such an obvious thing, but I lost lots of time with it and I can't find the solution... I am implementing a word counter plugin in JQuery which count the words in an *input* element at each keystroke, and show them in a div next to it.

My plugin is loaded like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#myOrigin").wordcounter({thresholdError : 65}); 
});
```

The plugin is structured like this:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.wordcounter = function(options) {
  var settings = { /* settings */ };

  if (options) { jQuery.extend(settings, options); }

  doWordCount = function() {
    var l = $(this).val().length;
    // etc...
  }

  $(this).keyup(doWordCount);
  return jQuery(this);
};
})( jQuery );
```

This works perfectly.

But now, I'd like the action to be performed when the document is loaded, so that if the input has text, the counter reflects that from the start, and not only after the first keypress.

I tried with `$(this).ready(doWordCount);` which fires the doWordCount method, but witin it `$(this)` refers to the document, not to the bound element!

How can I fix it?

Sorry again for such basic questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change last lines of your plugin like so

```
...
$(this).keyup(doWordCount).trigger('keyup');
return jQuery(this);
```

I'd prefer use `.triggerHandler()` instead, but this method isn't always suitable because it only affects the first matched element [as documentation states](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) (so it works if you have a selection of exactly one element)

Answer (score 2):

If you set up thedoWordCount function up as a method of an object. I always google jquery plugin patterns when doing this kind of thing. I always end up at this article:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern

Which I think should help you do what you want to do. I think you want to expose your thedoWordCount function.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! Will check it out carefully :)